# SQLite: Adding a column that contains the row position

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite table, and I need to add a column that contains the row position as given by a SELECT instruction.
The SELECT instruction contains two order clauses.

In case it's not clear, here is an example:
Given this data:

```
id        | c1      | c2 
===============================
a         | 1       | 2     
b         | 1       | 3     
c         | 1       | 1     
d         | 2       | 2     
e         | 2       | 3     
f         | 2       | 1
```

And this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY c1, c2
```

I need this resulting table:

```
id        | c1      | c2      | position
=========================================
a         | 1       | 2       | 2
b         | 1       | 3       | 3
c         | 1       | 1       | 1
d         | 2       | 2       | 5
e         | 2       | 3       | 6
f         | 2       | 1       | 4
```

How can I do it?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:
This is not the actual data or even the actual columns. it's just an example.**

Comment: Well, given those data particular, you could obtain the `position` values as `(c1 - 1) * 3 + c2`. Would that be all right?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use the minimum possible coefficient (3) given any particular dataset. How about something half way between the minimum (at risk of overlapping/incorrect ordering) and values that may induce an overflow?

Answer (score 1):

**This query should give you all of the fields that you are after:**

```
SELECT 
   ( SELECT COUNT(0)
     FROM MyTable T1
     WHERE (T1.c1 * 1000) + T1.c2 <= (T2.c1 * 1000) + T2.c2
   ) as 'position', 
   c1,
   c2,
   ID
FROM 
   MyTable T2
ORDER BY 
   (c1 * 1000) + c2
```

**Now, to order them by ID:**

```
SELECT ID, c1, c2, position FROM
  (SELECT 
     (SELECT COUNT(0)
       FROM MyTable T1
       WHERE (T1.c1 * 1000) + T1.c2 <= (T2.c1 * 1000) + T2.c2
     ) as 'position', 
     c1,
     c2,
     ID
  FROM
     MyTable T2 
  ORDER BY 
     (c1 * 1000) + c2
  ) T3
ORDER BY ID
```

**Notes**

- If the inner `Order By` does not work, you can dump the intermediate results into a temp table, then select from the temp table with the final Order By clause.
- The "1000" above is a coefficient. You need to make sure that this coefficient is greater than the maximum value of c2, but not so high that you get an integer overflow.

## Alternative Method

You can insert into a temporary table with an AutoIncrement column, and then select the values from that temp table based upon your desired ordering.

http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html